# Running gcloud on GCP instances doesn't work over ssh, but works on instance

Tags: bash, ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have an external instance IP which is setup correctly with my SSH keys. If I run the following code to access the GCP instance.

```
>> ssh <instance IP>
# Login happens
>> gcloud <some command>
# Gcloud outputs as expected
```

However, I can't run the `gcloud` command directly over ssh. That is

```
>> ssh <instance IP> gcloud <some command>
bash: gcloud: command not found
```

I believe this is the root cause of some issues I am seeing where I have permissions to run commands if I manually ssh and run in the interactive shell, but not if I pass the command through ssh.

I have tried

```
>> ssh <INSTANCE IP> -t "source ~/.bashrc; gcloud auth list"
bash: gcloud: command not found
>> gcloud compute ssh instance-name -- -t "gcloud"
bash: gcloud: command not found
>> gcloud compute ssh instance-name --command="gcloud"
bash: gcloud: command not found
```

and similar tricks around bashrc and gcloud, but there's nothing google-related in there I can see immediately anyway.

The instances are running Ubuntu 20.04, more or less fresh images. The problem is there between instances, or on my local machine connecting to instances.

I suspect I'm missing something simple here - any takers?

Comment: Have you tried running gcloud directly from the binary? e.g.: `ssh <instance-external-IP-addr> -t "/usr/bin/gcloud auth list"`

Comment: `gcloud` is configured per user. Are you using the same identity to login via both methods. Use the Linux command  `env` to double-check the environment under both login methods.

Comment: Thank you both - this helped track down the answer, below.

Answer (score 2):

After checking the binary location on ssh

```
>> which gcloud
/snap/bin/gcloud
```

The issue is caused by `/snap/bin` not being on PATH, as described [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/snappy/+bug/1659719).

That bug is being actively worked on now but doesn't appear to be complete yet. It specifically affects ubuntu, and the fact `gcloud` is installed as a snap in the default distribution.

This led to some misleading issues - in my case, `gcloud` was being used as an authenticator for docker, but lack of availability meant the error produced was a "missing permissions" error.

A workaround is

```
>> ssh <instance IP> PATH=$PATH:/snap/bin/ gcloud <some command>
```

Hope this helps someone!